# How to show a google satelite button in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

When you are on google maps, there's a button like this

[image]

You use it to change the type of map you're viewing, and as you move it updates where you are.

I'm developing an android app and I'm using google maps, now I'm using a simple button to change the type of the map, but I'd like to know if it's possible to add a button like this with the same behavior on my app.

**EDIT**

What I really want is to have a button that shows the live satellite as the google maps does, as you can see in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

On button Click set this line to change normal to satellite.

```
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

Comment: Hey, I can already do it, what I'm looking for is, to create a button with a map in it, like that picture.

Comment: As I described there, I have a simple button that I'm already able to change the type of the map, but what I really want is, that button to be like the google's map one

Comment: Download small size of google map satellite image form google and set this image on google map anywhere you want and then apply onClick() on this image.

Answer (score 0):

To change map types on button click in google maps, add `mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);` on your button. Example:

**maps.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onNormalMap"
            android:text="Normal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onSatelliteMap"
            android:text="Satellite" />
```

Now add the following methods in your activity file which.

```
 public void onNormalMap(View view) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    public void onSatelliteMap(View view) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }
```

`mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);` to show normal google map. `mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);` to show google satellite map. `mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);` to show terrain google map. `mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);` to show hybrid google map.

Comment: Hey, I can already do it, what I'm looking for is, to create a button with a map in it, like that picture.

Comment: As I described there, I have a simple button that I'm already able to change the type of the map, but what I really want is, that button to be like the google's map one

Comment: Just use an ImageButton or set the Button's background to a satellite image. To get the exact look, add some padding and shadow.

Comment: ,Look, it has to update live. as you move, it should update where you are, as the google map does. It's not only a map background, but a map background that updates as you move